# Databricks DBFS file not found after upload

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am using the following code in Databricks to upload files to DBFS. The files are showing when I do **dbutils.fs.ls(path)**. However when I try to read, I am getting a file not found error (see further down). Also, the file sizes are showing as zero?

```
def WriteFileToDbfs(file_path,test_folder_file_path,target_test_file_name):
  df = spark.read.format("delta").load(file_path)
  df2 = df.limit(1000)
  df2.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(test_folder_file_path+target_test_file_name)
```

Here is the error:

```
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/tmp/qa_test/test-file.parquet;
```

Here are the files listed but with zero sizes:
[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Databricks, this is expected behavior.

- For Files, it displays the actual file size.
- For Directories, it displays the size=0
- For Corrupted files displays the size=0

[image]

You can get more details using Azure Databricks CLI:

[image]

You can get more details using Databricks Explorer:

[DBFS Explorer](https://datathirst.net/projects/dbfs-explorer) was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks. You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

[image]